# Display table in PHP if statement

Tags: php, html-table

Can anyone help me how to display table inside PHP if statement.

Here's my code:

```
if( empty($errors))
{
ACTIVITIES \n
    echo ' <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Activity</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>                           
                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead> 

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Chicken Feeding</td>  
                <td>$price_chicken</td>         
                <td>$num_chicken</td>                           
                <td>$total_chicken</td>
            </tr>                       
        </tbody>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Fish Feeding</td>  
                <td>$price_fish</td>            
                <td>$num_fish</td>                           
                <td>$total_fish</td>
            </tr>                       
        </tbody>

        .................

    </table> ';
}
```

Comment: What is ACTIVITIES? It and the \n are not echoed out. Also, \n must be in double quotes or it will not render. What is the output?

Comment: nevermind the ACTIVITIES...=)...just the table

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php if( empty($errors)): ?>
ACTIVITIES \n
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Activity</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>                           
                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead> 

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Chicken Feeding</td>  
                <td><?=$price_chicken;?></td>         
                <td><?=$num_chicken;?></td>                           
                <td><?=$total_chicken;?></td>
            </tr>                       
        </tbody>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Fish Feeding</td>  
                <td><?=$price_fish;?></td>            
                <td><?=$num_fish;?></td>                           
                <td><?=$total_fish;?></td>
            </tr>                       
        </tbody>

        .................

    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the table code wrapped in single quotes, but there are PHP variables inside. PHP will not translate those variables unless you wrap the table in double quotes.

If this doesn't help, give us an idea of what the output looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a 2-dimensional array and looping through it to create a proper HTML table. This way, there's no hard-coding, so you can make as many rows/columns as you want. Here's the code, just change the array:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<?php
    $tableArray = [["Chicken Feeding", $price_chicken, $num_chicken],
    ["Fish Feeding", $price_fish, $num_fish]];
    foreach ($tableArray as $tableRow) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($tableRow as $tableCell) {
            echo "<td>$tableCell</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```